# Populating select-box options on changing pathfield in dialog of Adobe cq5

Tags: aem

In one of my dialogs, I have a field with an xtype of "pathfield". Depending on the value of this field, I want to change the options of the "select-box" (xtype="selection",type="select").

I have used listeners and added a function on events "change" and "dialogclose" for "pathfield" field.

I can call the servlet and it is sending the JSON response with options, however, I am unable to populate the select-box with these options.

The following is code of the dialog.xml

```
<select-product jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                fieldDescription="Select Product (Product Details Page)"
                fieldLabel="Select Product" 
                height="{Long}40" key="productPath"
                name="./productPath" 
                style="height:21px" 
                width="{Long}350"
                rootPath="/content/MY_MSM_PATH" 
                xtype="pathfield">

    <listeners jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        change="function(){ var selectBox=$('select[name=features]');
        $.getJSON('/bin/featuresservlet?path=' + this.value, 
            function(jsonData){
                $.each(jsonData, function(i,data){
                    $('<option>').val(data.value).text(data.name).appendTo('select[name=features]');
                });
        }); }"

        dialogclose="function(){ 
            var selectBox=$('select[name=features]');
            $.getJSON('/bin/featuresservlet?path=' + this.value, function(jsonData){
                $.each(jsonData, function(i,data){
                    $('<option>').val(data.value).text(data.name).appendTo('select[name=features]');
                });
            }); }" />

</select-product> 

<features jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" 
          fieldLabel="Select Features:"
          key="features" 
          name="./features" 
          type="select" 
          xtype="selection" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the set options method of the selection xtype. Modify your listener to something like this

```
dialogclose="function(pathfield){ 
        var dialog = pathfield.findParentByType('dialog');
        var selectBox = dialog.findByType('selection')[0]; //assuming this is the only selection you have
        $.getJSON('/bin/featuresservlet?path=' + this.value, function(jsonData){
            selectBox.setOptions(jsonData);
            selectBox.doLayout(flase,false);
        }); }"
```

The data returned by your servlet must be of the following format :

```
[
 {
    "value": "valueOfOption1",
    "text": "textOfOption1"
 },
 {
    "value": "valueOfOption2",
    "text": "textOfOption2"
 }

]
```

Reference : http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.Selection