# CQ5 - Dynamically populating options in selection xtype

Tags: aem, sling

I've been banging my head for hours on this now. I'm trying to dynamically populate options in a selection xtype and can't get it to work. Here is my dialog.xml

```
<resourceType
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
            title="Header Type">
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <headerType
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        fieldLabel="Header Type"
                        name="./headerType"
                        type="select"
                        xtype="selection">
                    <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                        <categories
                            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                            path="/content/admin/adminView/jcr:content/header-admin-content/cats/type.infinity.json"
                            width="500"
                            xtype="cqinclude" />
                    </options>
                </headerType>
            </items>
        </resourceType>
```

**The json that I'm producing for:**

```
content/admin/adminView/jcr:content/header-admin-content/cats/type.infinity.json
```

**Looks something like this:**

```
{"jcr:primaryType":"nt:unstructured","item_1":  
{"jcr:primaryType":"nt:unstructured","text":"small","parameter":"small"},"item_2":
{"jcr:primaryType":"nt:unstructured","text":"medium","parameter":"medium"},"item_3":
{"jcr:primaryType":"nt:unstructured","text":"large","parameter":"large"},"item_4":
{"jcr:primaryType":"nt:unstructured","text":"none","parameter":"none"}}
```

When I go to open the dialog nothing happens I just get a JS error **TypeError: snippet.xtype is undefined**

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Options for the `selection` xtype can be set dynamically in two ways

1. setting the [options](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.Selection#CQ.form.Selection-options) property to a path that returns a JSON array of options
2. Writing a function  that sets the options (using [setOptions](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.Selection#CQ.form.Selection-setOptions) method ) and passing this function as the value for [optionsProvider](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.Selection#CQ.form.Selection-optionsProvider) property.

In both the cases data returned in JSON must be an array.

To use method 1 , on the **headerType** node set `options` property to the path that will provide the JSON data. Set `optionsRoot` proprety to the name of the property that contains the JSON array. Set `optionsTextField` to the name of the property in the JSON data that should be text. Set `optionsValueField` to the name of the property in the JSOn data that should be the value.

A detailed tutorial on this can be found here : http://jenikya.com/blog/2013/04/dynamic-dialog-data-in-cq5.html

For method 2 refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708043/populating-select-box-options-on-changing-pathfield-in-dialog-of-adobe-cq5/25772802#25772802)

Comment: It seems like the options property is getting found but for some reason I think the optionsRoot is tripping me up. In the above json that I posted what would be the optionsRoot? Or do I need to create a specific options property containing the above json? Thanks for the help!

Comment: you will have to modify json , it expects an array . There is no array or root in the present form