# Appending AJAX in teaser dailog cq5

Tags: aem

I have dropped a simple teaser component in the *parsys* but dialog of teaser is not opening while checking in *firebug*, i found there is **"AJAX"** appending in URL of `dialog.infinity.json`, please find the image for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for including the image - that provided some missing information.  Your network traffic is showing a GET that succeeds quickly.  Then there is a JS exception "snippet.xtype" is undefined.  Have you registered the xtype for this?  Is the registration happening on this page?

Comment: I don't  register any X-type for this, i have dropped teaser component on the page and mapped with Campaign path with EDIT mode and it is working fine properly but when click again to change the campaign path without refresh the page it start appending _AJAX_ in it.

Comment: I just happened to notice some similar warnings with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698220/cq5-dynamically-populating-options-in-selection-xtype

Comment: It was related to some js will break then _snippet.xtype_ is become _undefined_ , issue is just create a new page and cq:include a teaser component which you can find it personalization group and do click on teaser component to assign values and again just to modify the values it will start breaking. dialog.infinity,json hit will start breaking because it has _AJAX_  appended in url, you can check in firebug.